# How to parse a string from the INDEX function Google sheets

Tags: date, web-scraping, indexing, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Trying to create a stock tracker for google sheets and for the Ex-dividend date I tried to use the index function

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML(concatenate("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/", D2,".TO?p=",D2,".TO&.tsrc=fin-srch"),"table",2),7,2)
```

This above function gives the output - "43965" instead of the actual data.

Comment: whats the desired output? share a copy of your sheet

Comment: The whole thing "April 29, 2020"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**43965** is a date value of **May 14, 2020**

[image: 0]

try:

```
=TEXT(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(CONCATENATE("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/", D2,
 ".TO?p=", D2, ".TO&.tsrc=fin-srch"), "table", 2), 7, 2), "mmmm dd, yyyy")
```